# UIAlertView with a textfield not popping up keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uialertview, ios8

I have a UIAlertView with a textfield inside (UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput) that automatically pops up a keyboard in iOS 7. However, when I upgraded to iOS 8, the keyboard didn't automatically popup and instead I would have to tap on the textfield to get the keyboard to popup. Is there anyway to restore that automatic keyboard popup to the UIAlertView textfield when I call it?

```
 UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"The amount?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [alertTextField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

**Update:** `[alertTextField becomeFirstResponder];` does not work nor does

```
 [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
 [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
```

Also, there is a textfield flashing indicator inside the textview, which is problematic because there is no actual keyboard that pops up automatically until the user taps on the textfield itself.

Comment: Use UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView as it is deprecated in iOS8, and here is a code for display alert view in iOS8 https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Xcode isn't letting me know that UIAlertView is deprecated...

Comment: Try it in `- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView`

Comment: @HamlierWalp ahve a look https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

Comment: Or you can see it in UIKit>UIAlertView.h, they write "UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead"

Comment: @KudoCC that didn't work either. But thanks for trying...any other ideas? It's almost like the alert view isn't being selected even though there is an textfield indicator flashing there...

Answer (score 4):

I had to unselect **"Connect Hardware Keyboard"** in the iOS Simulator **Hardware**->**Keyboard** menu options for running in iOS 8.

Comment: It was happening on my actual iOS 8 phone too

Answer (score 0):

If you add this line just after `[alert show]` it will make the keyboard pop up.

```
[alertTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately